# Kafka Deletes segments even before segment size is reached

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm playing with Kafka in my local machine, and I have added the following Topic configuration:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --topic topic1 config retention.ms=60000
bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --topic topic1 —config file.delete.delay.ms=40000
bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --topic topic1 --config segment.bytes=400000
```

My understanding is a segment will be deleted when the segment reaches out the segment size above defined (segment.bytes=400000) PLUS every single message within the segment is older than the retention time above defined (retention.ms=60000).

What I noticed is a segment of just 35 bytes, which conteined just one message, was deleted after the minute (maybe a little more)

Where I get that information? from a post that a Linkedin Engineer made about how the deletion process works:

> Retention is going to be based on a combination of both the retention
>   and segment size settings (as a side note, it's recommended to use
>   log.retention.ms and log.segment.ms, not the hours config. That's
>   there for legacy reasons, but the ms configs are more consistent). As
>   messages are received by Kafka, they are written to the current open
>   log segment for each partition. That segment is rotated when either
>   the log.segment.bytes or the log.segment.ms limit is reached. Once
>   that happens, the log segment is closed and a new one is opened. Only
>   after a log segment is closed can it be deleted via the retention
>   settings. Once the log segment is closed AND either all the messages
>   in the segment are older than log.retention.ms OR the total partition
>   size is greater than log.retention.bytes, then the log segment is
>   purged.

Link: [How the retention works](http://grokbase.com/p/kafka/users/159p6az5yg/log-retention-hours-not-working)

Answer (score 7):

There is one broker configuration - **log.retention.check.interval.ms** that affects this test. It is by default 5 minutes. So the broker log-segments are checked every 5 minutes to see if they can be deleted according to the retention policies.

topic1 configuration had retention policy set (**retention.ms**=60000), so if there was at least one existing message in an active segment of topic1, that segment would get closed and deleted if it was idle for long enough. Since log.retention.check.interval.ms is broker configuration, it's not affected by changes on the topic. Also retention.ms has to pass after the last message is produced to the segment. So after the last message is produced to that segment, segment will be deleted in not less than retention.ms milliseconds and not more than retention.ms+log.retention.check.interval.ms.

So the "segment of just 35 bytes, which contained just one message, was deleted after the minute (maybe a little more)" happened because retention check by chance happened almost immediately after the message was produced to that segment. Broker then had just to wait 60 seconds to be sure no new message will be produced to that segment (in which case deletion would't happen) and since there was none, it deleted the segment

Other topic1 configurations didn't play much role here.

**file.delete.delay.ms**=40000 just defined that after the broker has already decided to delete that segment it should wait 40 seconds to do that

**segment.bytes**=400000 didn't have any effect in this test. It defines that after 400000bytes are stored to the segment, it should be closed and the new one should be rolled out.

Answer (score 4):

You misinterpret some of the statements you cite:

> That segment is rotated when either the log.segment.bytes or the log.segment.ms limit is reached.

This clearly says rotation can be triggered by size or time. It's *or*, not *and*.

> Once that happens, the log segment is closed. [...] Once the log segment is closed AND either all the messages in the segment are older than log.retention.ms OR the total partition size is greater than log.retention.bytes, then the log segment is purged.

Thus, after a segment got closed by rotating triggered by time, it can be deleted regardless of its size.

Comment: Wait, I'm not pretty sure I miss interpret the statements. Let's break down it:

In my case the segment will be rotated when segment.bytes is reached (segment.bytes=400000). 
THEN, if all messages in the segment that was rotated, are older than retention.ms = 60000, THEN  delete the segment.

Comment: In fact I just checked the value related to segment.ms. It is set to 604800000 (168 hrs). So, we can even discard that segment.ms is set to a very low value (and with that discard the segments are being rotated because segment.ms property was reached before the segment.bytes property).

Comment: A segment can also be rotated when it is not full but its retention time passes. Thus this is not correct: "In my case the segment will be rotated when segment.bytes is reached (segment.bytes=400000)". In your case, the segment gets rotated because retention time passes. Furthermore, retention time is unrelated to "segment.ms" -- "segment.ms" is actually a third rotation policy/trigger in addition to segment size and retention time.

Comment: I think both, you and me, think the same, but maybe I'm not explaining it very well.

Let's see the retention.ms definition: 
"This configuration controls the maximum time we will retain a log before we will discard old log segments to free up space if we are using the delete retention policy."

So retention.ms is the retention period to discard old segments. I know retention.ms and segment.ms are NOT related. I'm not mixing both.

Comment: I agree with this statement. However, if you have a current segment that is not full yet, and retention time passed, the segment will be closed and turn into an "old log segment" even if it is not full. And thus, it will get deleted. Maybe the documentation is not clear enough -- but you observe this behavior -- so why do you think my explanation is not correct?

Comment: Right! that is what I was going to comment on. So there's no such thing as  "only those segments that were closed" (those one that reached 400000 bytes) can be candidates to be deleted". There's something wrong in the Tood Palino Statement.

Comment: I think this statement is correct. The question is about the right order of implications in the statement. If Todd says, "only those segments that were closed can be candidates to be deleted", he is right. IMHO, your miss conception is, that you assume than only full segments can be closed -- what is not true. A segment that is not full will be closed when either "segment.ms" or "retention.ms" passed.

Comment: Think about it as follows: If you have an open segment, and retention time passed Kafka wants to delete it. As it can only delete closed segments, it just does close the segment, to make it "delete able". So maybe the statement "only those segments that were closed can be candidates to be deleted" is miss leading, as you think it does imply that the currently open segment is "protected" agains retention time. But this implication is not there -- and Todd did not claim that this implication is there -- his phrasing is correct; maybe hard to understand though.

Comment: Then we agree. So my last question, mixing what Tood and you have said, is if at least the segment will be deleted if all messages in the segment are older than( in this case) retention.ms. according to my testing, I'd say yes.

Comment: I know its a very old post, but since it sheds a lot of light and wisdom on the matter, it would also be good to clarify since when the "retention.ms" starts to count. Since the segment opens, or since the last message was written into it?

Comment: The last message written counts -- if the start time would be used, messages might get deleted too early. Note, that retention ms is lower bound guarantee and data will be store for at least this amount of time.

Comment: Sometimes (for lower retention.ms) it may also happen that even before the data is flushed to disk, the segment may be marked as closed. Does Kafka flush to disk and delete them or directly clear the buffer memory?